# base tag showing 404 error if I clicked a stylesheet link in browser source

Tags: php, hyperlink, radix

I am using `<base>` tag in my website, and in pages am linking stylesheets like

```
stylesheet/default.css
```

Now when I browse the website and when I see the source and click the stylesheet link it shows 404, why is that so, I know am using base tag, so I need to use absolute path, but how to embed base tag while generating HTML page

Comment: do you have a live example?

Comment: you should not need to use the base tag ,why are you doing so ? also the url you wrote is relative , not absolute.